how to pass arguments to sol scripts
I'm working on a contract whose deploy scripts are like this:
contract MyContract is Script {
    function run(  
         address _feeRecipient,
         uint256 _feeBase,
         uint256 _taxBase,
         uint256 _minFee,)

        external
    {
       
        vm.startBroadcast();
        console.log("Deploying MyContract...");

        // Deploy the Index with fee recipient selected and emit an event.
        TestContract test = new TestContract (_feeRecipient);
        console.log("Test contract has been deployed at:", address(test ));
        vm.stopBroadcast();
}
}

how should I pass the arguments of run() in cli?
I don't get it
research and using gpt

Just run forge script with the --sig flag
forge script {CONTRACT_NAME} --sig "{FUNCTION_SIGNATURE}" {FUNCTION_PARAMS}

Real example that I've already used before, in case that is not clear yet:
forge script DeployCrossChainPoolManager --sig "run(address)" 0x36591DeBffCf727D5EEA2Cb6A745ee905Fae91C8


thanks, it worked

It's not possible to execute the script without having the default run() function, i.e., the run() without any params. As, without that, you'll keep facing this error:
Error: 
Function `run()` is not implemented in your script.

And, it's not possible (till now when using forge 0.2.0) to read command line arguments directly in the script, so you can store the params as environment variables in your .env file, like:
DEFAULT_ANVIL_PRIVATE_KEY=0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80
ANVIL_RPC_URL=http://localhost:8545
FEE_RECIPIENT=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
FEE_BASE=0
TAX_BASE=0
MIN_FEE=0

Then, execute this command to add environment variables into the terminal session:
source .env

Now, you can read / fetch these environment variables in your run() function, and then call your run(address,uint256,uint256,uint256) inside the same. So, your revised script would be:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import {Script, console} from "forge-std/Script.sol";
import {TestContract} from "src/TestContract.sol";

contract MyContract is Script {
    function run() public {
        run(vm.envAddress("FEE_RECIPIENT"), vm.envUint("FEE_BASE"), vm.envUint("TAX_BASE"), vm.envUint("MIN_FEE"));
    }

    function run(address _feeRecipient, uint256 _feeBase, uint256 _taxBase, uint256 _minFee) public {
        vm.startBroadcast();

        console.log("Deploying MyContract...");

        // Deploy the Index with fee recipient selected and emit an event.
        TestContract test = new TestContract(_feeRecipient);
        console.log("Test contract has been deployed at:", address(test));
        vm.stopBroadcast();
    }
}

Finally, You can execute this using the forge script command, like:
forge script script/MyContract.sol:MyContract --rpc-url $ANVIL_RPC_URL --private-key $DEFAULT_ANVIL_PRIVATE_KEY --broadcast

NOTE: It’s highly recommended to avoid using and entering private key in plain text. So, you can just import your private key corresponding to a particular account that you want to use into an encrypted keystore using cast wallet import, and then you can use the account name and sender wallet address in the command via —-account and —-sender flags, allowing you to enter the keystore password in an interactive manner.
So, the above forge script can be rewritten as:
forge script script/MyContract.sol:MyContract --rpc-url $ANVIL_RPC_URL --account $YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME —-sender $YOUR_WALLET_ADDRESS --broadcast


I tried it in many ways but it keeps saying Function run() is not implemented in your script. because I did not provide the arguments correctly, can you write the literal command for me, please? please put address zero as FEE_RECIPIENT and 1 for other variables

Sorry, I misunderstood that and posted incorrect answer. Now, I've corrected that by providing a workaround, as it's not possible to execute the run() function with args directly.
